# Create a folder with a choosen name in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, directory, directory-structure, folderbrowserdialog

I programmed a small GUI with Tkinter where I ask the user for a directory to save certain images, via `filedialog.askdirectory`. With that information, I am able to create a folder in that directory using `os.mkdir()`, but I need to predefine its name ( i use a structure like year_month_day....).

Is there anyway in tkinter or using os library, where the user could define the name of the folder and then created? The idea is when the Windows folder browser is open, they could go the desired path and create a folder with the name they want

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```py
import os
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter as tk

# Dir select
def selectPath():   
    path_ = askdirectory()
    path.set(path_)

def create_file():  
    print("folder_name: ", folder.get())
    print("path_name: ", path.get())
    dirs = os.path.join(path.get(), folder.get())
    if not os.path.exists(dirs):
        os.makedirs(dirs)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Tips:','Folder name created successfully!')
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Tips','The folder name exists, please change it')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Create folder')
root.geometry('400x380')

path = tk.StringVar()   # Receiving user's file_path selection
folder = tk.StringVar() # Receiving user's folder_name selection

tk.Label(root,text = "Target path:").place(x=50, y= 250)
tk.Entry(root, textvariable = path).place(x=110, y= 250)
tk.Button(root, text = "Path select: ", command = selectPath).place(x=265, y= 250)


tk.Label(root,text = "Folder name:").place(x=50, y= 300)
tk.Entry(root,textvariable = folder).place(x=110, y= 300)
tk.Button(root, text = "Submit: ", command = create_file).place(x=265, y= 300)

root.mainloop()
```

`path` and `folder` variables are the path selected and the folder name created by the user.

It will look like this on my computer:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Better use `os.path.join(path.get(), folder.get())` instead.  Also avoid using both `from tkinter import *` and `import tkinter as tk`, the later is enough.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, your suggestion is very good, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by putting an `input` widget called as a text widget. After inputting there a name of the folder and selecting the path using the `filedialog` you can make a function which will create a directory.

```
def create_dir()
    name = file_name.get() # took from the input
    path = os.path.join(dir, name) # dir is a directory taken from the filedialog
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
from datetime import datetime
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

datestring = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #Formats the date according to year,month,day. 
#You can check out datetime for more info
default_folder = 'Adrain-{}'.format(datestring)

if os.path.exists(default_folder) == True: #Only creates a new folder when non-existing
    pass
else:
    os.mkdir(default_folder)

file_directory = filedialog.askdirectory(title = 'Select the target folder for saving             
records', initialdir = default_folder)
```